# Delete first element of array before pushing a new one

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

I'm using FireSharp to manage an array of items in a Firebase Realtime database.

I'm trying to implement a kind of queue of 30 messages.

I want to manage only 30 messages and if a new message is received, the first in time order should be deleted.

How can i do it?

In this moment I'm just adding items to the array in this way:

```
IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig{
        BasePath = _RHDLLConfig.firebaseJsonUrl
};
IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(config);

client.Push("signals", rh);
```

I want to delete the first element before to push a new one...

The array looks like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the first element of the array

```
signals = signals.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: so it means that before to push I have to do a GET of the entire array and the work on it ?

Comment: You can also loop the array and make signals[0]=signals[1], signals[1]=signals[2] and so on... Then you make signals[19] your new one.

Comment: This is because in c# arrays will always be fixed sized.

Comment: actually my array is structured so I have to manage it using lists

Comment: Lists are actually easier to work with... You could just do signals.RemoveAt(0);